# Download .eml file with Microsoft Graph C#

Tags: c#, graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have some problem with Microsoft Graph.I would like to download the attachments present in a specific email. I have verified that the type of object returned after this:

```
 var attachments = graphClient.Me.Messages[msg.Id].Attachments.Request().GetAsync().Result;
 foreach(var item in attachments) {
         var current_attachment = graphClient.Me.Messages[msg.Id].Attachments[item.Id].Request().GetAsync().Result;
}
```

is an object of type Attachment.
Now, I would like to download this object (current_attachment) but I saw that the property ContentBytes isn't available.
I have tried to cast the object to FileAttachment, but it throw an exception.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This should be fairly straightforward.  Specifically:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message
>
> Even though Outlook does not save messages in MIME format, there are
> two ways you can get an Outlook message body in MIME format:
>
> You can append a $value segment to a get-message operation on that
> message. If the message is attached to an Outlook item or group post,
> you can append a $value segment to a get-attachment operation on that
> item or group post. In either case, your app must have the appropriate
> permissions to access the Outlook item or group post in order to apply
> the get-message or get-attachment operation.
>
> You can then save the message body content in a .EML file and attach
> the file to records in business systems, such as those for CRM, ERP,
> and bug tracking.

Here is an example:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp
>
> Gets the MIME content of a message in the signed-in user's mailbox.
>
> ```
> GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
>
> var stream = await graphClient.Me.Messages["4aade2547798441eab5188a7a2436bc1"].Content
>   .Request()
>   .GetAsync();
> ```

You can write "stream" to a disk file like this:

```
string path = @"\my\path\myfile.eml";
using(FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)) 
{  
    stream.CopyTo(outputFileStream);  
}
```

The resulting .eml file will be the complete email, including all attachments.

Comment: I was able to access the attachment, but i would like download it to local drive. Before using Graph I used the following code to download the attachments:

 if (attachment.GetType() == typeof(FileAttachment))
 {
      var item = (FileAttachment)attachment; // Cast from Attachment
      System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(di.FullName + "\\" + item.Name, item.ContentBytes);
 }
but now, the attachment type is ItemAttachment and therefore doesn't contain the ContentBytes property. How can I use System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes to write the bytes of the attachment with this new type of attachment?

Comment: Your subject line asked "Q: How can I download .eml file with Microsoft Graph C#?"  The code I cited does exactly that: it gives you a stream; you can write the stream to an .eml file.  The file will be the *complete* email, including *all* attachments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a similar call to get an InputStream for the ItemAttachment as you would do to get the InputStream for a Message.
See code below in java but will be similar for c#.  The java API is missing the .content() option on Attachments but you can build the url and append $value instead.

```
URL requestUrl = graphClient.users("user@***.com").messages("*****").attachments("****").buildRequest().getRequestUrl();
InputStream is = new FileAttachmentStreamRequestBuilder(requestUrl.toString() + "/$value", graphClient, null).buildRequest().get();
// save the file
Files.copy(is, Paths.get(fileName + extension), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```